# Trigger periodic builds in Jenkins only if a build has not run in a given period

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a maven project which references some external repositories and uses Jenkins for continuous integration. The git repository has several branches and it is not unusual for some git branches to go for a while without commits. I've had problems in the past where I've returned to a branch, committed some changes only for the build to fail because one of the external repositories has moved or is temporarily offline.

To get notification of such problems ahead of time I want to combine periodic builds with builds triggered when I commit changes. I can simply turn on both but if a build has already run 5 times today there is no need to trigger a build as I'd have noticed if there were build issues.

I am unable to find an elegant way of only triggering a build if it hasn't run in the last 24 hours. Is there a plugin or combination of plugins that will allow me to do this without external scripts to create files and monitor builds?

Comment: Why not simply trigger a build @daily in Jenkins ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Builds take quite a long time and consume resources that I'd rather not use if I've already done several builds that day (because I've committed to the repos). If it is actually hard to detect the period since a build occured then that's what I'll do.

Comment: Via REST API you could get the information when the last build has been done...? Create another job which checks that and let trigger it via this ?Apart from that a maven project should not reference external repository this should be handled by a repository manager which will solve those issues.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'd like a similar configuration.